# Installation of pywinrm module on RHEL 6 with Python 2.6 does not proceed due to cryptography. It points to cffi

Tags: python, pip, ansible, rhel6

I have been trying to install pywinrm module on my Ansible control server which is running on RHEL 6 with Python 2.6 (pre-installed).

But the dependency cryptography module fails with the error :

```
    Installing collected packages: cryptography
    Running setup.py install for cryptography ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-QE26MW/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-BhDfJs-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Couldn't find index page for 'cffi' (maybe misspelled?)
    No local packages or download links found for cffi>=1.7
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-build-QE26MW/cryptography/setup.py", line 307, in <module>
        **keywords_with_side_effects(sys.argv)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/core.py", line 113, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 221, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs.pop('setup_requires'))
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 245, in fetch_build_eggs
        parse_requirements(requires), installer=self.fetch_build_egg
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 538, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, self, installer)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 780, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer) # try and download/install
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 792, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 293, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 466, in easy_install
        raise DistutilsError(msg)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('cffi>=1.7')

    ----------------------------------------
    Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-QE26MW/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-BhDfJs-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-QE26MW/cryptography/
```

There were suggestions to update the cffi module, But that didn't help as it states it is already up-to-date:

```
    [root@BLRCSLLIQQA0005 cryptography]# pip install -U cffi
    DEPRECATION: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team, please upgrade your Python. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.6
    /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
      SNIMissingWarning
    /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
      InsecurePlatformWarning
    Requirement already up-to-date: cffi in /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages
    Requirement already up-to-date: pycparser in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (from cffi)
```

From the Installation doc of [cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/), I see `libffi-devel` as a dependency. But when I try to install the same I get:

```
     cryptography]#  sudo yum install redhat-rpm-config gcc libffi-devel
    Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, subscription-manager
    This system is receiving updates from Red Hat Subscription Management.
    rhel-6-server-rpms                                                                                                                                  | 3.5 kB     00:00     
    rhel-server-dts-6-rpms                                                                                                                              | 3.4 kB     00:00     
    rhel-server-dts2-6-rpms                                                                                                                             | 3.2 kB     00:00     
    Setting up Install Process
    Package redhat-rpm-config-9.0.3-51.el6.noarch already installed and latest version
    Package gcc-4.4.7-18.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
    No package libffi-devel available.
    Nothing to do
```

This is my pip stack,

```
    cryptography]# pip freeze
    DEPRECATION: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team, please upgrade your Python. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.6
    ansible==2.3.1.0
    asn1crypto==0.23.0
    Babel==0.9.4
    Beaker==1.3.1
    cas==0.15
    certifi==2017.7.27.1
    cffi==1.11.2
    chardet==3.0.4
    cups==1.0
    cupshelpers==1.0
    decorator==3.0.1
    enum34==1.1.6
    ethtool==0.6
    firstboot==1.110
    freeipa==2.0.0a0
    httplib2==0.7.7
    idna==2.6
    iniparse==0.3.1
    iotop==0.3.2
    ipaddress==1.0.18
    ipapython==2.1.3
    iwlib==1.0
    kerberos==1.1
    lxml==2.2.3
    M2Crypto==0.20.2
    Magic-file-extensions==0.1
    Mako==0.3.4
    MarkupSafe==0.9.2
    matplotlib==0.99.1.1
    ndg-httpsclient==0.4.3
    netaddr==0.7.5
    nose==0.10.4
    numpy==1.3.0
    ordereddict==1.2
    paramiko==1.7.5
    passlib==1.7.1
    pyasn1==0.0.12a0
    pycparser==2.18
    pycrypto==2.0.1
    pycurl==7.19.0
    pygpgme==0.1
    pykerberos==1.1.14
    pyOpenSSL==0.10
    python-dateutil==1.4.1
    python-default-encoding==0.1
    python-dmidecode==3.10.13
    python-keyczar==0.71rc0
    python-ldap==2.3.10
    python-meh==0.11
    python-nss==0.11
    pytz===2010h
    pyxdg==0.18
    PyXML==0.8.4
    PyYAML==3.10
    requests==2.18.4
    requests-kerberos==0.11.0
    rhnlib==2.5.22
    rhsm==1.1.8
    scdate==1.9.60
    scservices==0.99.45
    scservices.dbus==0.99.45
    simplejson==2.0.9
    six==1.9.0
    slip==0.2.11
    slip.dbus==0.2.11
    slip.gtk==0.2.11
    smbc==1.0
    SSSDConfig==1
    urlgrabber==3.9.1
    urllib3==1.22
    virtinst==0.600.0
    xmltodict==0.11.0
    yum-metadata-parser==1.1.2
```

Please let me know if you need any further information. This is a major hurdle. I couldn't find any blogs or posts with same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python2.6 is depreciated and no longer maintained. Try upgrading it to latest version

Comment: As RHEL 6 requires Python2.6 for proper functioning, I did try to install Python2.7 alongside. But the pip still picks up from Python 2.6. Followed [link] (https://tecadmin.net/install-python-2-7-on-centos-rhel/) 
I have 
`# python -V
Python 2.6.6`
`python2.7 -V
Python 2.7.13`
But pip points to 2.6 
`pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (python 2.6)`
Posts about installing easy-install to 2.7 and then a pip for 2.7 did not help.

Comment: you should always use python virtual environment.

Comment: Virtualenv did work perfectly. With a separate environment being created for 2.7 and no more worries about the python version being referred by Ansible. So 2.6 is past then :)